# Hydrate my React app with HTML from the API instead of static HTML from index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, create-react-app

I am building a React application using the create-react-app. My application will rely on an API for initial HTML using which I will hydrate my app and add React components to it dynamically during load and serve to the browser.

I planned to call the API in `componentDidMount()` of the initial app component and replace the static HTML with the dynamic one from the API using  `ReactDOM.render(element, document)` I can replace the whole DOM (including `<html></html>`).

Is there any other approach which doesn't have a dirty path like this, or is there any other best practices for doing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using React on the backend then [`ReactDOM.hydrate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate) is available since React 16.

Else removing the backend rendered DOM should be preferably done before the first call to `ReactDOM.render`.